# One Error Message Needed If 2 Fields Are Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net contact us form which has 'Tel No.' and 'Email' fields. What i'm after is one error message for if both these fields are blank when the form is submitted but i can't figure it out, brain fart i think lol

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <asp:Label ID="TelFieldLabel" class="col-md-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Contact No." AssociatedControlID="TelField"></asp:Label>
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <asp:TextBox ID="TelField" runat="server" class="form-control" type="Number"></asp:TextBox>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <asp:Label ID="EmailFieldLabel" class="col-md-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Email address" AssociatedControlID="EmailField"></asp:Label>
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <asp:TextBox ID="EmailField" runat="server" class="form-control" type="Text"></asp:TextBox>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">         
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" SetFocusOnError="True" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="EmailField" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">Email address is not a valid format.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
          <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator2" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please enter either a phone number of an email address." ClientValidationFunction="ContactFields_ClientValidate" OnServerValidate="PrefContact_ServerValidate" />
     </div>
</div>
div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="pull-right">
               <asp:LinkButton ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientclick="ShowProcessingPopup();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Submit</asp:LinkButton>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My email address also hase a validation error assigned to it as you can see from the abve.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC!

Comment: `jquery` validation or `asp` validation?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Any. Would prefer `asp` if possible but if not i'm open to any solution as long as the code is tidy lol

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry i added the wrong tag.

Comment: I do not thing `asp`'s `RequiredFieldValidator` will handle your scenario as you said _one error message for if both these fields are blank when the form is submitted_. But yea `jquery` can do

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Thats fine do you know how i can achive this then please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET way to do it is,

Markup

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" 
    Display="Dynamic" 
    ForeColor="Red" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter either a phone number of an email address." 
    ClientValidationFunction="ContactFields_ClientValidate" 
    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator2_ServerValidate">
```

JavaScript

```
function ContactFields_ClientValidate(source, arguments) {
    var telephoneField = document.getElementById("<%= TelField.ClientID %>");
    var emailField = document.getElementById("<%= EmailField.ClientID %>");
    if (telephoneField.value == "" && emailField.value == "") {
        arguments.IsValid = false;
    }
    else {
        arguments.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

Code-Behind

```
protected void CustomValidator2_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (TelField.Text.Trim() == "" && EmailField.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What `asp Validator` do i use and how do i set it up?